Mi Box Stuck in Boot Loop After Update - Can't Mount /Cache in Recovery Mode
My Mi Box suddenly began restarting 10 seconds after booting up. I guess it might be an issue with the update.
I would appreciate any help or ideas.
(Just a thought: can I connect via ADB over USB in recovery mode and do something from there? I actually tried it, but the device isn't appearing in the list.)
I tried wiping the cache and doing a factory reset from the recovery menu. However, in the recovery menu, I couldn't wipe the cache, data, or install new ROMs (there are some tutorials for that) because it keeps saying "can't mount /cache, invalid argument." Someone suggested mounting /system first and then wiping the cache, but that didn't work either and it still says "can't mount /cache."
